# Putting MCMCglmm objects in Anova() or Manova()

Tags: r, anova, mixed-models, mcmc, manova

I am using `MCMCglmm` package to perform mixed-model analysis. If I have data look like:

```
df_test <- data.frame(ID = 1:10, a = 171:180, b = 71:80 + rnorm(10),
  age = factor(c(rep("young", 3), rep("mid", 4), rep("old", 3)),
    levels = c("young", "mid", "old")))
```

For linear models, I can easily do `summary(Manova(lm(cbind(a, b) ~ age + 0, data = df_test)))` to get the table and see the clear effect on age (please ignore the collinearity issue here).

However, what if I use `MCMCglmm` to consider the mixed effects of ID? Let's say the `MCMCglmm` object is called "mc_model", how can I use `Manova` or similar methods to look at the effects of (multiple) categorical (with numerous levels) variables?

Thanks!